# Print float without using printf() in c

Tags: c, floating-point, printf

I am trying to code my printf() function. I wanted to print float/double values. This is what I managed to do so far.

```
static void ft_float(va_list *ap, t_flag *flags)
{
  double myfloat;
  signed long int decipart;
  signed long int intpart;

  myfloat = va_arg(*ap, double);
  if (myfloat < 0)
  {
      ft_myputchar('-');
      myfloat *= -1;
  }
  intpart = (signed long int)myfloat;
  ft_putnbr(intpart);
  ft_myputchar('.');
  myfloat -= intpart;
  myfloat *= 1000000;  //upto 6 decimal points
  decipart = (signed long int)(myfloat + 0.5); //+0.5 to round of the value
  ft_putnbr(decipart);
}
```

As you can see for obvious reasons the code works good for floats like 1.424352, 12313.1341414 etc. But not when the value after the decimal point is less than 1, for example 1.004243, 12313.0001341 etc.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Converting floating point numbers to strings correctly [is hard](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/~dyb/pubs/FP-Printing-PLDI96.pdf). Also, what is “doesn't work?” Please tell us what happens. “It doesn't work” is not an error description.

Comment: Isn't there any simpler way to convert them?

Comment: It's not easy, unless you are extremely careful, you are often getting wrong results. See the paper I linked for an algorithm that does that correctly. Are you satisfied with a solution that is almost correct as in “yields almost correct results?”

Comment: What gets printed for 1.004243 and 12313.0001341?

Comment: the function prints 1.004243 as 1.4243 and 12313.0001341 as 12313.1341

Comment: That's because you neglected to print the decimal part in a field width 6 with leading zeros.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how can I get the exact number of leading zeros

Comment: If `decipart` is not equal to zero, then you need `5 - (int) log10(decipart)` leading zeros. If it is equal to zero, then you need 6.

Comment: 004243 x 1000000 = 4243 , you need to consider the fact that leading zeros has no meaning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function printf can be used to pad the value with zeroes. Flag `0` sets the padding to be 0, and the width specifies the minimum number of characters written, padding at the left side is used if necessary.

Simply printf `decipart` with the format: `"%06ld"`.

Comment: Thank you, that answers my question.!